# Web scraping: images show when shared to Facebook but not my app. Error 401 No signature found

Tags: web-scraping, rss, facebook-opengraph

I'm building a news curation service that uses RSS feeds from various sources including The Guardian.

When I try to pull the image from The Guardian articles, I get: **Error 401 No signature found** error.

However when you share the article to Facebook etc, the image will show in the feed.

For example, this is the image link to a current article:
https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/dd92773d05e7da9adcff7c007390a746930c2f71/0_0_2509_1505/master/2509.jpg?w=1200&h=630&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=crop&crop=faces%2Centropy&bm=normal&ba=bottom%2Cleft&blend64=aHR0cHM6Ly91cGxvYWRzLmd1aW0uY28udWsvMjAxNi8wNi8wNy9vdmVybGF5LWxvZ28tMTIwMC05MF9vcHQucG5n&s=bb057e1ec495b0ec4eb75a892b6a190c

From this page: https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2016/mar/22/world-water-day-quiz-are-you-a-fount-of-wisdom

Is there a way for me to use the image like Facebook is able to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error that you're facing is probably caused because you're trying to use some intranet resources without being logged or authenticated into the system.

Using the following code you'll be able to fetch a smaller version of your picture. It will read html source of the page provided by you and search for an img with the specific requirements

---

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.theguardian.com/global-development/2016/mar/22/world-water-day-quiz-are-you-a-fount-of-wisdom'
html_source = requests.get(url).text
#print(html_source)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')

img = soup.find_all('img', {'class':'maxed responsive-img'})
```

---

Then you can `print` you results:

**Only the first img:**

```
print(img[0]['src'])
```

Output:

```
https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/dd92773d05e7da9adcff7c007390a746930c2f71/0_0_2509_1505/master/2509.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=ba3a4698fe5fce056174eff9ff3863d6
```

---

**All img results:**

```
for i in img:
    print(i['src'])
```

Output:

```
https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/dd92773d05e7da9adcff7c007390a746930c2f71/0_0_2509_1505/master/2509.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=ba3a4698fe5fce056174eff9ff3863d6
https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/6ef58c034b1e86f3424db4258e398c88bb3a3fb4/0_0_5200_3121/2000.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=ea8370295d1e2d193136fd221263c8b8
https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/e1c2b1336979a752a68c3c554611bc28aa0a4baa/0_290_4324_2594/2000.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=eef138cefe66834919c3544826a3e468
https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/37df4e7b52dfd554d431f7d439cdd1a137789fa4/0_0_4256_2553/2000.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=9e461f6739325cf3524a1228f5f7e60b
```

Comment: Thanks! I see now, thanks to you, that the images with the 'maxed responsive-img' classes are the only versions that will work for me. I appreciate your help! :)